# Why is the deviance $\chi^{2}_{n-p}$ distributed?

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, generalized-linear-model, chi-squared-distribution, deviance

Consider a GLM with vector of parameters $\boldsymbol{\beta}$, the maximum likelihood estimates of the non-saturated model (no. of parameters = $p < n$) is $\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}$ and the deviance is $D^{*} = \frac{D}{\phi}$. Likewise, $\boldsymbol{{\beta}_{SAT}}$ is the vector of parameters under the saturated model and $\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}_{SAT}}$ is the maximum likelihood estimate of parameters under the saturated model.

It was shown in my lecture notes that $D^{*} = 2\{l(\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}_{SAT})-l(\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}})\} = 2\{l(\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}_{SAT})-{l(\boldsymbol{\beta}_{SAT})}\}-2\{l(\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}})-l(\boldsymbol{\beta})\}+2\{l(\boldsymbol{\beta}_{SAT})-l(\boldsymbol{\beta})\}$.

I know that $l(\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}_{SAT})-{l(\boldsymbol{\beta}_{SAT})}$ is asymptotically $\chi_{n}^{2}$ distributed, $l(\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}})-l(\boldsymbol{\beta})$ is asymptotically $\chi_{p}^{2}$ distributed and $l(\boldsymbol{\beta}_{SAT})-l(\boldsymbol{\beta})$ is just a positive constant, let's call it $v$.

Here's what I don't get:

a) using properties of chi-squared distribution, how do I get that the scaled deviance is asymptotically distributed as $\chi_{n-p}^{2}(v)$, where $v$ is the non-centrality parameter? Edit: is it Wilks' theorem?

b) What does it mean in my notes when it says "if the model with $p$ parameters is correct, then $D^{*}$ is asymptotically distributed as $\chi^{2}_{n-p}$, that is, the non-centrality parameter is approximately 0 under the null"?